# My C program isn't recognizing valid input, think it's because of a newline issue

Tags: c, scanf, newline

I have a C program that is supposed to evaluate whether the user entered a `H` or a `M`. I have some input validation to ensure that the user enters either `H` or `M`. However, when those are entered, the procedure treats it like the user entered something else. I have a feeling that this is because `scanf` is adding a newline character to the input which causes it to fail the comparison. I'm trying to find ways to strip out this newline character, but I've had no luck. I've tried putting `getchar()` after the `scanf`, but that didn't work. I've tried using `fgets` and that didn't work either. I tried changing the format indicator from `%s` to `%c` and that didn't work.

Here is the entire procedure:

```
char GetEmployeeStatus()
{
    // declare variable
    char strEmployeeStatus = "";
    int intEmployeeStatusResult = 1; // assume valid input

    do
    {
        // get user input
        printf("Please enter the employee's status: H for hourly or M for management. \n");
        intEmployeeStatusResult = scanf("%s", &strEmployeeStatus);

    } while (intEmployeeStatusResult == 0 || strEmployeeStatus != "H" || strEmployeeStatus != "M");

    return strEmployeeStatus;
}
```

Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: strEmployeeStatus is a single character, but you use it with string specifier, you need a char array, or %c instead of %s. `strEmployeeStatus != "H"` is also wrong, you are comparing a single character with a string.

Comment: @xing, that didn't work.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but this is the basics of the language, it seems that you are in need of a [good C book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/6865932)

Answer (score 1):

Add the correct headers. Then enable compiler warnings and compile it again.

Mainly, you're mixing up string literals (`"foobar"`) with character literals (`'x'`); this is what GCC has to say about the initialization:

```
blah.c: In function ‘GetEmployeeStatus’:
blah.c:6:30: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     char strEmployeeStatus = "";
                              ^~
```

With similar warnings from the comparisons.

Also consider what the `%s` conversion for `scanf()` does. From the Linux man page:

> s
> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to the initial element of a character array that is long enough to  hold  the  input
> sequence  and  the  terminating  null  byte  ('\0'), which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs
> first.

Here, in your code, `strEmployeeStatus` is just one char. You are giving `scanf()` a pointer-to-char correctly, though, so the compiler has a hard time warning about that.

```
char strEmployeeStatus;
scanf("%s", &strEmployeeStatus);
```

Then, the loop condition: `strEmployeeStatus != "H" || strEmployeeStatus != "M"`. That's (X is not A OR X is not B). What happens in an expression like this when X is A, B, or C? What are the values of the subexpressions, and what's then the value of the whole OR expression in each case?

Answer (score -1):

I talked with someone IRL, and we fixed the problem. The issue wasn't with `scanf` at all. The problem was my compound `OR` statement. The line below:

```
intEmployeeStatusResult == 0 || strEmployeeStatus != "H" || strEmployeeStatus != "M"
```

will always evaluate to `true` even if `H` or `M` is entered. I changed the line to:

```
intEmployeeStatusResult == 0 || strEmployeeStatus != "H" && strEmployeeStatus != "M"
```

and the program works as intended now.